# 600W PSU max Watt load

Tags: electrical-power, power-supply-unit

I have purchased an EVGA 600W Silver PSU.

It is connected to the following: Motherboard + CPU + SSD + 3 x Video Card (RX 470 with riser cables).

I have a watt meter which I have connected to the PSU and the overall wattage it shows is 540W-550W.

I would like to know if it is safe to run such a configuration say for 24 consecutive hours?

Also, general, if the limit of PSU is say, X watts, how much reserve we should leave in order to be safe?

Comment: This might be a better question for SuperUser, except it's probably been answered quite well elsewhere.

Comment: It is connected to the mining gpu rig which  basically is a kind of server. And the issue might cause faults. That is why I  asked it here. Anyways i will copy it in the superuser as well thanks.

Comment: Don't copy please. If deemed necessary, community members here with sufficient privileges will migrate it.

Comment: But really, there are a plethora of documents and articles out there dealing with this question. What homework have you done so far?

Comment: I found an online psu power calculator and put all my hardware details in. It showed 480W and recommended 520w psu. But my watt meter shows 550w. And i wonder of for a 600w gpu  50w reserve is enought to be safe. The psu itself got a bit hot

Answer (score 1):

Things to consider:

Using a Wattmeter you'll really want to measure the peak wattage. This will be the power required at startup and the power drawn while under load (use an appropriate stressing application for this).

The rule of thumb I'm familiar with is that for longevity and health you'd like the peak load draw to be 60-70% of the rated maximum for the power supply. I don't claim this to be gospel truth, but it's something I've personally heard and stuck to.

Also, a power supply with a higher wattage rating will actually be MORE efficient when powering components that are a smaller total fraction of its possible wattage. This generally should directly equate to lifespan on a power supply.

Your numbers have you running at more than 90% of that PS' maximum load, and I do not believe that is healthy for the system.